# Javascript Inject window.addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, uniswap

I want to Inject https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap.
And I Input "document.body.addEventListener('click',function(event){console.log(event)})" in chrome console.
I can get the event normally by clicking other places. But after clicking to select ETH, in the pop-up module dialog box, I can’t get the event by clicking

I want to know what caused the failure to get the click event

Comment: To which element you need to add event listner ?

Comment: Just added your code via console, works fine

Comment: Maybe the element in question (or an ancestor) has a click event callback assigned that calls `event.stopPropagation()`, so that the event will be stopped from bubbling up to the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean theres no event on the open modal.. because otherwise it works for me also.
it seems there are another click event from the reach-portal element which will be do as CBroe sais above a stopPropation or something else. If you remove the second event listener from the reach-portal you are able to do it.

Or, change the click event to "mousedown" or something else will work in this case.

**update**:
Or even easier, add useCapture to the addEventListener.
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(event){console.log(event)},**true**)

Comment: Yes, I want to inject and listen to remote page click events in electron.
I was not familiar with js, and it solved my problem.Thanks